# Error adding database to a mvc3 application

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I found this error when I was adding my database to visual studio 2010 for making a MVC3 application. I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
    The database 'C:\USERS\KAPIL.AGRAWAL\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\DT\DT\APP_DATA\DTRIAL.MDF' 
    cannot be opened because it is **version 661**. 
    This **server supports version 655** and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
    **Could not open new database** 'C:\USERS\KAPIL.AGRAWAL\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\DT\DT\APP_DATA\DTRIAL.MDF'. 
    CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
    An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file c:\users\kapil.agrawal\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\dt\dt\App_Data\dtrial.mdf failed. 
    A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, 
    or it is located on UNC share.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you been able to eliminate any of the possible causes listed in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the database was created with SQL Server 2008 R2 (version 611) and you are trying to open it with SQL Server 2008 RTM or SP1 (version 655). You cannot backup/restore or detach/attach from a higher version to a lower version. You could upgrade your local database server to SQL 2008 R2. See [this article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx) for more information.